# C# uploading png image to Azure loses transparency

Tags: c#, azure, png, transparency, azure-blob-storage

When uploading a png file to Azure Blob Storage, the transparency turns black.

I have tried using both:

CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStream(stream)

CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFile(file)

Here is the C# MVC Controller code I am using:

```
public ActionResult _UploadAdImage()
    {
        var model = new ImageViewModel { status = "failed" };
        try
        {
            string stagingResult = "failed";
            string fileExtension = string.Empty;
            var imageFileName = string.Empty;
            if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                var file = Request.Files[0];

                imageFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).Replace(".", "").ToLower();

                // Test to make sure the png is still transparent at this point.
                //var image = Image.FromStream(file.InputStream);
                //var fileName = Server.MapPath("~/Files/" + imageFileName + ".png");
                //image.Save(fileName);

                var media = new MediaModel
                {
                    MediaStorageType = Common.MediaStorageType.TemporaryFile,
                    FileName = imageFileName,
                    FileStream = file.InputStream,
                    ContentType = "image/" + fileExtension
                };
                media.FileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                azureComponent.SaveMedia(media);
                stagingResult = "success";

            }
            model.status = stagingResult;
            model.url = "/image/tempfile/" + imageFileName;
            model.mediaId = imageFileName;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            model.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        }


        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Here is the logic to save the file to Azure:

```
        public void SaveMedia(MediaModel mediaModel)
    {
        var cloudStorageAccount = GetCloudStorageAccount(mediaModel.MediaStorageType);

        var cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        var cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(GetContainerName(mediaModel.MediaStorageType));

        cloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();

        var blob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(mediaModel.FileName.ToLower());

        using (mediaModel.FileStream)
        {
            blob.UploadFromStream(mediaModel.FileStream);
            blob.FetchAttributes();
            blob.Metadata["Submitter"] = "Automated Encoder";
            blob.SetMetadata();

            // Set the properties
            blob.Properties.ContentType = mediaModel.ContentType;
            blob.SetProperties();

        }
    }
```

Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

Here is a link to the original and final images:

[Original Image](https://empiricaltest.blob.core.windows.net/test/originalimage.png)

[Final Image](https://empiricaltest.blob.core.windows.net/test/finalimage.png)

Comment: Your code looks ok to me (though there're some redundant calls that you can avoid however they should not cause the issues you're facing). Will it be possible for you to share the image file you're trying to upload and the URL of the image file in blob storage?

Comment: Thank you for sharing the images. What I noticed is that the original file is `75964 bytes` whereas the final file is only `13225`. Please check in your controller code as to why there's such a difference in the size.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, thank you for pointing that out. An existing function that gets the image from the blob was converting it to a jpg and since the src for the image element did not have an extension, I did not noticed this. I have resolved the code error by converting the image to the proper format. Thanks you!